# How can you act only on those elements that are in a particular view state in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, viewstate

I have a class that I need to perform some actions on but **I only want to perform the action on those elements of the class that are currently shown**.

For example, this code hides all elements of the `pie` class, whereas I only want to effect the elements that are currently shown and not act on the ones that are currently hidden:

```
$(".pie").click(function () 
{      
  $(".pie").hide;
});
```

(toggle is not what I'm looking for here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [:visible pseudo-selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible).

So something like this:

```
$(".pie").click(function () 
{      
  $(".pie:visible").hide;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the is function and then the visible selector. Either or does the same but I like the is function because it is more human readable by others who may not be super familiar with selectors. Here is an example:

```
$(".pie").click(function () 
{      
if ($(".pie").is(':visible')){
  $(".pie").hide;
}
});
```